# Objects not appearing in SceneBuilder in fx:id post running

Tags: java, javafx

I have a code where I want to increase the height of a stick (basically a rectangle) on detecting a key press.
Initially, on detecting key presses the code was printing out text, which worked perfectly fine
However after I created a rectangle object, wrote the code to increase it's height, and interfaced the rectangle with the corresponding fx:id and ran it, it threw the following error

So I went back to the scene builder, and now when I tried to check if the rectangle was associated with the correct fx:id, I simply saw that the id had disappeared. This is a recurring problem. Each time I create a new rectangle, I can see the fx:id there. But right after running the code, the id disappeared.

The Error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle.getHeight()" because "this.this$0.stick" is null
    at com.example.demo2@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.example.demo2.SceneController$1.handle(SceneController.java:105)
    at com.example.demo2@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.example.demo2.SceneController$1.handle(SceneController.java:83)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2194)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2715)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:150)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:249)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:542)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

The bugged controller.java code

```
package com.example.demo2;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SceneController {



    @FXML
    private Rectangle stick;

    @FXML
    private Stage stage;

    @FXML
    private boolean gameIsRunning = false;

    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.Label pausedLabel = new Label();

    @FXML
    private Scene scene;

    @FXML private Scene gameScene;

    @FXML
    private Scene pausedScene;

    @FXML
    private Parent root;


    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.Button closeButton;


    @FXML
    public void switchToMainMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml")));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void switchToMainMenuFromGame() throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml")));
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void createBridge(KeyEvent event){
        switch (event.getCode()){
            case C -> stick.setHeight(stick.getHeight()+10.0);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void switchToGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        gameIsRunning = true;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("game-view.fxml")));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        gameScene = scene;

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                switch (keyEvent.getCode()){
                    case ESCAPE -> {
                        System.out.println("paused game");
                        pauseGame();
                        try {
                            switchToPausedScene();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    case Q -> {
                        try {
                            switchToMainMenuFromGame();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    case C -> {
                        System.out.println("creating bridge");
                        stick.setHeight(stick.getHeight()+10.0);
                    }
                    case X -> System.out.println("switching sides");
                }
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void switchToPausedScene() throws IOException{
        gameIsRunning = false;
        if(null == pausedScene){
            root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("paused-menu.fxml")));
            scene = new Scene(root);
            pausedScene = scene;
        }else{
            scene = pausedScene;
        }
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (Objects.requireNonNull(keyEvent.getCode()) == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    try {
                        switchToGameSceneFromPaused();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void switchToGameSceneFromPaused() throws IOException{
        scene = gameScene;
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        gameIsRunning = true;
    }


    @FXML
    protected void onExitButtonClick() {
        Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }


    @FXML
    private void pauseGame(){
        gameIsRunning = false;
    }

    @FXML
    private void resumeGame(){
        gameIsRunning = true;
    }




}
```

and my game-view.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="966.0" prefWidth="540.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo2.SceneController">
   <children>
      <Rectangle fx:id="stick" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="6.0" layoutX="287.0" layoutY="225.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="6.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: `stick` will be initialized in the controller that is created by the `FXMLLoader` that loads `game-view.fxml`. It won't be initialized in the controller on which `switchToGame(...)` is invoked (you haven't shown the code for how that controller is created, but it looks like it is a controller created by some other `FXMLLoader`).

Comment: Consequently, it looks like you are using the same controller class for two different FXML files. This is always a bad idea: use a different controller class for each FXML.

Comment: You should never set anything that has been annotated `@FXML` to another value (e.g. your `pausedLabel`).  You should not annotate objects not defined in FXML as `@FXML` (likely your `scene`, `gameScene` and `stage` objects, and the `gameIsRunning` boolean value).  You don't need to annotate public methods `@FXML`, though it is usually best to define them as private and annotate them `@FXML` instead.  You can get the scene from the stage, you don't need to create a new scene every time you set the root node of the scene.  Use the non `ea` versions - `ea` is for unstable early access code.

Comment: Abstract your game logic (e.g. `gameIsRunning`) outside of your controllers and [share it with controllers using MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx) if needed.